# What is the Big O for this enqueue method?

Tags: java, queue, big-o, enqueue

I wrote code for an enqueue method in a singly linked list and I'm wondering if anyone can tell me the Big O is for this code. I at first assumed it was O(n) because of the loop. However, the loop will always iterate a specific number of times depending on how many items are in the list. This makes me believe it's actually O(1). Am I wrong?

```
public Node<T> enqueue(T data){
        Node<T> toQueue = new Node<>(data);
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = toQueue;
            return toQueue;
        }
        Node<T> lastNode = this.head;
        while(lastNode.next != null){
            lastNode = lastNode.next;
        }

        lastNode.next = toQueue;

        return toQueue;
    }
```

Comment: However, the loop will always iterate a specific number of times *depending on how many items are in the list*. How many items in the list is your `n`, so `O(n)`.

Comment: Exactly what @StephB said - you answered your own question. If your loop depends on `n` then it is `O(n)` - even if it is half of `n` or a tenth. Still `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the following excerpt from the question:

> However, the loop will always iterate a specific number of times depending on how many items are in the list.

This is a correct statement.

Please, note the dependency on the input size:

> iterate a specific number of times depending on how many items are in the list

Therefore, the algorithm has the linear time complexity — `O(n)`.

## Linear time complexity

A slightly reformatted excerpt from the article: [Time complexity: Linear_time - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time):

> An algorithm is said to take **linear time**, or `O(n)` time, if its time complexity is `O(n)`. Informally, this means that the running time increases at most linearly with the size of the input. More precisely, this means that there is a constant `c` such that the running time is at most `cn` for every input of size `n`. For example, a procedure that adds up all elements of a list requires time proportional to the length of the list, if the adding time is constant, or, at least, bounded by a constant.

A slightly reformatted excerpt from the article: [Big O notation: Orders of common functions - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions): let's refer to the corresponding row:

> Notation: `O(n)`
>
> Name: [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time)
>
> Example: Finding an item in an unsorted list or in an unsorted array; adding two `n`-bit integers by [ripple carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_carry_adder)

Answer (score 1):

> However, the loop will always iterate a specific number of times depending on how many items are in the list. This makes me believe it's actually O(1).

> Am I wrong?

Your reasoning is wrong.

A complexity analysis of an algorithm needs to take account of all possible inputs.

While the number of elements in a single given list can be assumed to be constant while you are looping, the number of elements in *any* list is not a constant.  If you consider all possible lists that could be inputs to the algorithm, the length of the list is a variable whose value can get arbitrarily large<sup>1</sup>.

If we call that variable `N` then it is clear that the complexity class for your algorithm is `O(N)`.  (I won't go into the details because I think you already understand them.)

The only way that your reasoning could be semi-correct would be if you could categorically state that the input list length was less than some constant `L`.  The complexity class then collapses to `O(1)`.  However even this reasoning is dubious<sup>2</sup>, since the algorithm as written does not check that constraint.  It has no control over the list length!

On the other hand, if you rewrote the algorithm as this:

```
public static final int L = 42;

public Node<T> enqueue(T data){
    Node<T> toQueue = new Node<>(data);
    if (this.head == null) {
        this.head = toQueue;
        return toQueue;
    }
    Node<T> lastNode = this.head;
    int count = 0;
    while(lastNode.next != null){
        lastNode = lastNode.next;
        if (count++ > L) {
           throw InvalidArgumentException("list too long");
        }
    }

    lastNode.next = toQueue;

    return toQueue;
}
```

then we can legitimately say that the method is `O(1)`.  It will either give a result or throw an exception within a constant time.

---

<sup>1 - I am ignoring the fact that there are practical limits on how long a simple linked list like this can be in a Java program.  If the list is too large, it won't fit in the heap.  And there are limits on how large you could make the heap.

2 - A more mathematically sound way to describe the scenario is that your algorithm is `O(N)` *but* your use of the algorithm is `O(1)` because the calling code (not shown) enforces a bound on the list length.</sup>